# How to print a string consisting of a char repeated a variable number of times in C?

Tags: c, printing, char

In Python, one can print `XXXX` using `print "X"*4;` Is there any easy equivalent in C?

Comment: Do you just want to *print*? Python does much more than that: It actually creates a new string.

Comment: And the comparison is bogus: In Python you're multiplying a *string* with a number, not a char with a number.

Comment: In a loop (number of steps are defined by input value), I just want to print "x" in each step increasing by 2.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have much in the way of builtin/standard library, so you'd have to go through the process of allocating a new buffer and concatenating four strings to it, then freeing the buffer, it's simpler just to print "X" four times.

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<4; ++i) {
   printf("X");
}
printf("\n");
```

You could write your own, though.

```
char* x(const char* s, unsigned int reps) {
   size_t len = strlen(s);
   char*  buf = (char*)malloc(len*reps + 1);

   while (reps--) {
      memcpy(buf, s, len);
      buf += len;
   }

   *buf = '\0';
   return buf;
}


char* repeated = x("X", 4);
printf("%s\n", repeated);
free(repeated);
```

But as you can see, the result is almost as long.

Comment: Thanks! I just wondered if there is some easier implementation that you first suggestion :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Welcome to C:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    printf("X");
```

Comment: is that really true?? I just started learning C and I'm pretty confused about such easy things ...

Comment: If you are familiar with python you are also familiar with some basic programming languages constructions like loops (for, while, do..while), variables assignment and so on... However C is meant to be produce fast code, and, therefore, you will work in a lower abstraction level than python. If you want to print a char four times, you have to explicitly say it: print the char four times. In python you would use a higher level operator `*` which works for strings and that creates a new string built with 4 characters, like in `print "X"*4;` In C strings are nothing more than an array of char.

Comment: Thanks! That clarify a lot :). So if I want to do it let's say in "pythonic" way I need to write may own implementation for it? Just like @ikegami said before

Comment: Yes, exactly... In C you are working "closer" to the code generated that will be executed by the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  In C you would need to use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no standard library in C that can do that, but you can always implement easily with yourself. A simple implementation in C:

```
char * strmul(const char * src, size_t times) {
    size_t s_len = strlen(src);
    char * res = (char*)malloc(s_len * times + 1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < times; i++) {
       strcpy(res + s_len * i, src);
    }
    return res;
}
```

---

Improved version as suggested by @ikegami

```
char * strmul(const char * src, size_t times) {
    size_t s_len = strlen(src);
    char * res = (char*)malloc(s_len * times + 1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < times; i++) {
       memcpy(res + s_len * i, src);
    }
    res[s_len * times + 1] = '\0';
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Fails for times==0, and you'd get faster code from `memcpy` than from `strcpy`.